# como usar una variable de sql en c#

Tags: c#, sql-server

Tengo una tabla sobre un salon de clases y también quiero contar los alumnos con promedio por encima y por debajo del promedio; tengo dos variables para eso, aquí el SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE alumnos (
IDALUMNOS INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
ID AS ('AL' +RIGHT('00'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR, IDALUMNOS), (2))),
NOMBRE NVARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
APELLIDO NVARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
GENERO NVARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
edad INT NOT NULL,
PROMEDIO INT  NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO alumnos VALUES('Alan', 'Smith', 'M', 20, 95)
INSERT INTO alumnos VALUES('Juana', 'Perez', 'F', 20, 95)

GO
CREATE PROC calcprm

AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @PROMEDIO AS INT
END

SELECT

sum(case WHEN PROMEDIO >70 then 1 else 0 end) AS PASARON,
sum(case WHEN PROMEDIO <70 then 1 else 0 end) AS QUEMARON 
FROM alumnos
```

Las variables `PASARON` Y `QUEMARON` cuentan lo que su nombre indican, ahora quiero usar esas variables en unas etiquetas (label) en una  aplicación WinForms c#. ¿Podrían decirme la forma mas simple de hacer esto?. Aquí mi código c#:

```
namespace Datos
{
   public class C_Datos
   {
       SqlConnection conexion = new   SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["aulacon"].ConnectionString);
    
       public void calcprom(C_Entidades alumno)
       {
          SqlCommand CMD = new SqlCommand("calcprm", conexion);
          CMD.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
          conexion.Open();
          CMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("PASARON", alumno.Pasaron);
          CMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("QUEMARON", alumno.Quemaron);
          CMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("PROMEDIO", alumno.Promedio);
          CMD.ExecuteNonQuery();
          conexion.Close();
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124893/discussion-between-japv-and-jachguate).

Comment: alan y que pasa con los que tienen el promedio igual a 70, esa opcion no la contemplas, los que pasan creo deben tener su promedio >= 70

Comment: Tienes razon, muchisimas gracias por la correccion

Answer (score 0):

Deberías revisar un poco sobre la documentación de ADO.NET o buscar ejemplos. Pero para intentar ayudarte, ahí va mi respuesta:

```
   public void calcprom(C_Entidades alumno)
   {
      SqlCommand CMD = new SqlCommand("calcprm", conexion);
      CMD.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
      conexion.Open();
      CMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("PASARON", alumno.Pasaron);
      CMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("QUEMARON", alumno.Quemaron);
      CMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("PROMEDIO", alumno.Promedio);
      CMD.ExecuteNonQuery();
      conexion.Close();
   }
```

El comando "CMD.Parameters.AddWithValue" se utiliza siempre y cuando tu procedimiento almacenado necesite parámetros, el primer valor es el nombre de la variable y el segundo es el valor que le envías.

En tu caso, entiendo que lo que deseas es recuperar los valores desde la base de datos hacia tu proyecto .NET C#. En ese caso deberias ejecutar un "CMD.ExecuteReader" y retornar una lista o en su defecto retornar un Datatable. (Recomendable un List).

Revisa el siguiente link:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ado-net-code-examples